# Is Xcode 4 ready for iOS development or still too beta?

Tags: xcode, ios

I am just starting iOS/iPhone development and I would like to start using XCode 4 instead of XCode 3.2. Is XCode 4 stable/feature complete enough for beginning iPhone development or should I stick with XCode 3.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say no, it's not ready.  I tried using it as my main development environment for about a week, and eventually switched back to 3.2.  For one thing it crashed fairly regularly, but I could get passed that.

The big thing that caused me to switch back was a bug where the iOS simulator would think that certain resources existed in my app that didn't.  Deleting the app from the simulator didn't work, cleaning the project didn't work, and deleting the derived data folder didn't work.  Since it's not officially released, finding help for problems like this is a pain as well.

This is just one instance of the kind of problems you'll run into while using it, so I'd recommend avoiding it for now.

Answer (score 5):

I have run into far too many problems using beta versions of XCode, especially since you can't really have two versions of XCode one the same system. Apple already has a history of releasing things to developers before they are truly ready (just look at iAds for the iPad which were released months ago and have yet to deliver a single ad). So, if even Apple isn't ready to label XCode 4 as ready-to-go then you can rest assured its not really ready to go.

I recommend sticking with 3.2. That's what I'm doing until XCode 4 is officially supported.

Using XCode 4 calls everything you do into question. Having a problem with an API? Maybe it's XCode, maybe its your code, maybe its a bug in the API. You just don't know.

Comment: +1 The official line (from the preview 6 read me) is: "Xcode 4 is beta software. Continue to use Xcode 3.2.x for production development.". To do otherwise would be extremely foolhardy as you've outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xcode 4 if you do not plan on using the current version (Preview 6) for submitting apps to the App Store.

iOS Dev Center:

> Xcode 4 Developer Preview 6 includes
>   iOS SDK 4.2, bug fixes, and additional
>   features. To compile submissions for
>   the App Store, continue to use Xcode
>   3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2.